# Ubuntu HP Elitebook 8460P will not boot

Tags: boot, laptop, hp, 23.04

I have a HP laptop wish worked well with Ubunto 20.04.
I tried to upgrade to 23.04 but I don't get it done.

After I managed to install and the laptop restarts I isn't able to find the OS on de harddisk

I already  done a bootrepair but still have problems.

Is there anybody who has a sollution?